# Python data and matrices

Tags: python, matrix

I create a 5 by 5 matrix as follows:

```
a = [[0 for y in range(5)] for x in range(5)]
print(a)
```

I have a file input.dat

```
1 2 NA
1 4 6
1 5 1
2 3 NA
3 3 10
4 5 5
```

Using this file, I need to populate my matrix so that if column 3 value is less or equal to 5, matrix input should have a value 1. The matrix should be symmetric, meaning that the first and second columns can be exchanged `(1,3) = (3,1)`. If value is NA, the value should remain zero.The value should remain zero if there is no pair (for example (1,3) is zero in the matrix shown. The final product should look as follows:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Thank you so much for your time and help in advance!

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  You have dumped a homework problem here with no apparent attempt to solve it yourself.

Comment: I have tried everything I could, I am a beginner, please do not judge so harshly. I am not in school either, I try to figure things out on my own. I have no idea where to even begin looking so that I can get input directly from a file into a matrix and I have not found examples. I am not asking for a full solution, only guidance where to begin. I have tried to learn how to code but because of responses like this, I feel like it is not the most friendly environment. Thank you for your time and your invaluable comment.

Comment: Again, please repeat the intro tour.  "Guidance on where to begin" is outside the scope of Stack Overflow.  The judgement is merely on a question that does not appear to serve the stated purpose of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a loop like this:

```
index =   [(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 5)]
condition = ['Na', 6, 1, 'Na', 10, 5]
for i in range(len(index)):
    if condition[i] != 'Na' and condition[i] <= 5:
            m, n = index[i][0] - 1, index[i][1] - 1
            a[m][n] = 1
            a[n][m] = 1
```

you can get the following result

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

There's a mistake in the solution you provided. `(1, 4) <= 5 --> False --> a[1, 4] = 0` should be the case.

---

Here is the read in of data included using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('input.dat', sep=' ')
data.Na = data.Na.apply(lambda x: int(x) if not x == 'Na' else 0)

for i in range(len(data)):
    if data.Na[i] != 'Na' and data.Na[i] <= 5:
            m, n = data.iloc[i, 0] - 1, data.iloc[i, 1] - 1
            a[m][n] = 1
            a[n][m] = 1
```

provides the solution as well:

```
a =
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and for pointing out my mistake too, you are a star! I will now work on getting the input from the file, thank you!

Comment: If this answer helped you, I'd be happy if you mark it as correct. Glad to help!

Comment: thank you again for all your help; I really appreciate it. I also found a really cool way to represent the matrices as plots so if anyone ever stumbles here, ```plt.imshow(a);
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()``` is a nice way to visualise larger matrices. Thank you for your help and encouragement. [https://www.dropbox.com/s/x7urmfbdgo55zr8/experiment-threshold20.png?dl=0]